# How to include model attribute automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have the `User` model which define the following attribute:

```
public function getAvatarUrlAttribute()
{    
    return 'https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=' . $this->email;
}
```

I usually access to this attribute using something like:

```
User::find(1)->avatar_url;
```

**Problem**

I need to return all the attributes of the `User` model when I execute this code:

```
$users = User::whereRoleIs('doctor')->get();
```

The collection returned to `ajax` doesn't contain `avatar_url` attribute though. How can I include all the attributes automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell Laravel that you want to include it when you convert it to an array using [`appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

```php
<?php

class User {

    protected $appends = ['avatar_url'];

    public function getAvatarUrlAttribute()
    {    
        return 'https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=' . $this->email;
    }

}
```